# How can I execute multiple find commands in a single line?

Tags: bash, find, python

I have the following find commands. I would be using python to call these commands and run them. It is a requirement that I run these commands in one go.

find commands

```bsh
find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;
find /path/to/files2 -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

When I run them in bash like so, I get an error **find: paths must precede expression: `find'**

```bsh
find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \; find /path/to/files2 -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

But when I run it like this I don't get an error.

```bsh
find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \; && find /path/to/files2 -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I would like to understand why I don't get an error with `&&`. And what is the best way to run consecutive `find` commands.

It is a requirement for me that I should run them like below. I would prefer to know a solution which can accomplish the below, but I'm also open to suggestions.

```py
cmd1 = 'find ... \; '
cmd2 = 'find ... \; '
cmd3 = 'find ... \; '

# This utilises string concatenation
full_cmd = cmd1 + cmd2 + cmd3

# I need to run them in one call.
# It's hard (not impossible) to change this since it is a part of a bigger code base
python_func_which_runs_bash(full_cmd)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command with the `&&` does run the commands consecutively, however the second command only runs if the first exits successfully. You could use `;` in place of `&&` if you want the second command to run unconditionally.

Note that the *escaped* `\;` doesn't count - it's escaped precisely so that the shell **doesn't** see it as a conjunction, and instead passes it as an ordinary argument to `find`.

See also:

- [Why are the backslash and semicolon required with the find command's -exec option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913198/why-are-the-backslash-and-semicolon-required-with-the-find-commands-exec-optio/20913251)
- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)